Property does not exist on type 'unknown'
i have a code like this:
import { QueryClient, useQuery, useQueryClient, UseQueryOptions } from "@tanstack/react-query"

export function useQueryFactory(getConfig: (queryClient: QueryClient) => UseQueryOptions) {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    const config = getConfig(queryClient)

    return useQuery(config)
}

class Account {
    static findMany() {
        return {
            async queryFn() {
                return {
                    accounts: [{
                        id: 123
                    }],
                }
            },
            queryKey: ["Country", "findMany"],
        }
    }
}

export function AccountsList() {
    const { isSuccess, data } = useQueryFactory(Account.findMany)

    if (isSuccess) {
        // error here Property 'accounts' does not exist on type 'unknown'
        const { accounts } = data

        console.log(accounts)
    }
}

Why this error is happened and how to fix this?
Playground

• This is really a "tanstack" question too, isn't it? You need to know those types in order to answer this. Maybe it should be tagged as such? • From my inspection it seems like what you need is for useQueryFactory to be generic as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

I will take that as an affirmation that my previous comment fully addresses the question, and I will write up an answer soon.

Your problem is that useQueryFactory() returns a UseQueryResult<unknown, Error> no matter what. The output type of that function does not depend on its input. So when you use the result of that function, you get a data property of type unknown.
If you want the return type of useQueryFactory() to depend on the type of the getConfig argument, you'll need to make the function generic. From my look at useQuery(), you want to change the call signature to be something like this:
export function useQueryFactory<T>(
  getConfig: (queryClient: QueryClient) => UseQueryOptions<T>
) {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    const config = getConfig(queryClient)
    return useQuery(config)
}

Note the addition of the type parameter T.  Now the function call signature looks like
/* function useQueryFactory<T>(
     getConfig: (queryClient: QueryClient) => UseQueryOptions<T>
   ): UseQueryResult<T, Error> */

meaning it returns a UseQueryResult<T>, and therefore depends on the type of getConfig().  Now everything just works:
export function AccountsList() {
    const { isSuccess, data } = useQueryFactory(Account.findMany)
    if (isSuccess) {
        const { accounts } = data
        //      ^? const accounts: { id: number; }[]
        console.log(accounts)
    }
}

Playground link to code
